# NPM Package to Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with NodeJs and I need a regular expression to get dots and '+' symbols.

I have the pattern: " /.|+/ " (I try my regex in this website: https://regex101.com/)

I had checked some modules, and I found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/regex but I just get 'false' when I insert the words: 'house', 'hou.se' and 'hou+se', It doesnt work to me.

I run the module online, in this website: https://runkit.com/npm/regex

Can someone help me?

Comment: You should escape dot and plus signs using backslash: `/\.|\+/`.

Comment: it doesnt work with this module. I need to get other module.

Comment: What result you want to get? Could you present some example of what you try to achive?

Comment: I'm using this module:  https://runkit.com/npm/regex, I need a regular expression to find dots and '+', for example, get a true if the word is hou.se or hou+se. I need a module o a regular expression that works in this module.

Comment: You don't need any special package for regex, check this code http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_nodejs_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMclNuMkZDNFh1VzA

Comment: Thanks, this works, I was thinking all time that I must use a module =(

Comment: Please read basic regexp documentation, such as that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), in particular about the dot. When you ran this in regex101, did you not see the bright red indication saying ERROR?

Comment: @ofca He's obviously trying to test for the presence of a dot or a plus sign.

Answer (score 0):

Dot (`.`) matches everything, so it needs to be escaped.

Plus (`+`) is a special character indicating "one or more," so it too must be escaped.

`g` means "global" so it will find all matches.

Try this:   `/\.|\+/g`

or a simpler solution presented by @torazaburo in the comments: `/[.+]/`

Comment: I dont have problem with the regular expression, my problem is with the module of nodejs, I need one module when check a regex.

Comment: 1) Your regex is not okay. 2) There's a major problem with this package where it will only match against the full string you pass into `.test()`. There's a related bug here: https://github.com/aaditmshah/regex/issues/4. If this question is just asking to help you find another module to solve your problem, I'm going to mark it as should-be-closed. Why even use a module in the first place? Just use JavaScript's built-in regular expressions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Why not `[.+]`?

Comment: @torazaburo Because I didn't think of it after reading the format in Leonardo's question - thanks.

Comment: @J.Titus Thanks for adding it to your answer. Personally, I think this question should be closed as a typo, especially since regex101, which the OP claimed to have used, marks his regexp with a big red SYNTAX ERROR message.

Comment: @torazaburo, it works, put this: /\.|\+/ in regex101 and you will see that you can searchs dots and plus symbols.

Comment: @LeonardoCavani He's saying that the previous version you had in the original question before it was edited (`/.|+/`) threw an error in regex101.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks for editing the wording in my answer.